# Function to find equal distances between all N points whose sum is as close to S as possible

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, optimization

I am tasked with writing an algorithm to graph N points in X/Y coordinates where one point is on (0;0) and where between each of those points the distance is somewhat equal (to an extent of course) and the sum of those distances is somewhat equal to S. So it would be a complete graph. Obviously this is an optimization task from linear algebra and I'd solve it using one of the gradient methods. The problem is that I can't seem to think of a function for this problem. I would highly appreciate if someone could help me out with this or at least give a good source where I should look into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are $N$ points then there are $k = \frac{N(N-1)}{2}$ edges, i.e., $k$ distances you want equal, but their sum is supposed to be $S$, hence each one must be $S/k$ (approximately). So...you could look to optimize
$$
f(P_1, \ldots, P_N) = \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=i+1}^N \left(d(P_i, P_j)-\frac{S}{k}\right)^2
$$
Equivalently, you could optimize
$$
g(P_1, \ldots, P_N) = \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=i+1}^N \left(kd(P_i, P_j)-S\right)^2
$$
which has the charm of having no fractions. :)

Comment: Yes, that seems like something I could try to optimize. I'll look into it. Thank You! :)